# AppStore Promotional Offer is not applying discounted price

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

My new app has certain features that require auto-renewing subscriptions.  I set up my subscription and set its pricing on AppStore Connect.

I also want to offer a promotional offer which discounts the monthly subscription fee. I also set this up on AppStore Connect.

When I test the app on my iPhone, the subscription prices comes up at full price and not discounted promotional price.

Is there anything special I need to do for promotional price to apply? Do I need to use "Introductory Offers" instead? I thought "Promotional Offer" was the right one for me because it applies to all new users for a set period. The introductory offers seem to have a set start/end dates.